# mysql check how many days are valid between 2 dates with from and end date

Tags: mysql

i have a table for offers that contains 2 columns from_date and to_date and the values 2014-09-15 and 2014-10-31.

Then i have a user that wants to book from 2014-09-10 til 2014-09-25, what i would like to do is to count how many days from the user dates matches the from_date and to_date on the offers table.

can anyone advise on how to make this count

thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to find the difference between the latest start date and the earliest end date:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF (GREATEST(from_date, '2014-09-10'), 
                 LEAST(to_date, '2014-09-25')
       )
FROM   mytable
```